# I have an error with Visual Studio Code, when typing, it doesn't show errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use `Visual Studio Code` and I noticed something when I restarted the app. When I was typing, I didn't see errors popping up whiles coding. Can someone tell me why this happens?

eg:
[image]

That's not what it would exactly look like but whiles I was coding it would come up.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using VScode python extension?

Reloading VScode python extension can be a solution.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned was the linting of the python in the VSCode.

It can be provided by Language Server and the linter packages. You can add these to the `settings.json` file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

Refer to [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) for more details.